# Confusing definitions in Liu's Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In Qing Liu's book *Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves* I came across several confusing definitions. Several times he defines a notion only for a subclass of schemes/morphisms but later he is never *explicitly* mentioning these extra conditions again. Here are some examples:

- Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme, and let $x \in X$ be a point. We say that $X$ is *regular* at $x$ if [...]. We say that $X$ is *regular* if it is regular at all of its points. **Question:** If he later says "Let $X$ be a regular scheme", then is it implicit that $X$ is locally Noetherian? If so, then why doesn't he say "A scheme is called regular if it is locally Noetherian and [...]"?
- Let $X$ be a reduced Noetherian scheme. Let $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n$ be the generic points of $X$. We say that a morphism of finite type $f:Z \rightarrow X$ is a *birational* morphism if [...]. **Question**: If he later says that a morphism $f:Z \rightarrow X$ of (arbitrary) schemes is birational, then is it implicit that $X$ is reduced Noetherian and that $f$ is of finite type? If so, then why doesn't he say "A morphism $f$ is called birational if it is of finite type, if $X$ is reduced Noetherian and if [...]"?
- Now it gets really confusing: Let $X$ be a reduced locally Noetherian scheme. A proper birational morphism $\pi:Z \rightarrow X$ with $Z$ regular is called a *desingularization* of $X$. **Question:** He defined *birational* only for reduced Noetherian schemes. What is *birational* for reduced locally Noetherian schemes? Is his *desingularization* now automatically of finite type?

Edit:

1. In Liu's book I found the following definition now: We say that a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is *proper* if it is of finite type, separated and universally closed. So, first of all, I think that this definition is now given in the non-confusing style, and second, this implies that the desingularizations above are of finite type (although it doesn't answer the locally Noetherian/Noetherian question).
2. I was asking "...then why doesn't he say that..." because I wasn't sure (and I'm still not sure) if there is some "higher truth" in this style of definition. Of course nobody except for Liu himself can answer this but perhaps someone else has more experience than I have and can give an explanation for this...

Comment: As to "why" only the author can provide a definite answer. Although he seems to be participating in MO, it would appear to be less argumentative if you asked him directly. I personally have always thought that "Let X have property P. We say that X is Q if ..." means that in talking about X that are Q, we only consider X with P (seems a bit tautological). It's a great devise for not dragging along monstrous sequences of standard assumptions (kind of like saying "in this book, all rings are commutative and have an identity").

Comment: Yet it is strange that in 3) a weaker property (local Noetherianity) than an implicit one (Noetherianity) is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: As for 1), the explanation is as given by Victor. As far as I know, regularity is defined only for locally noetherian schemes, so regular scheme are supposed to be locally noetherian, as least in my book. So yes, maybe it is better so say a scheme is regular if it is locally noetherian and etc. For 2), the reason is different. I only consider birational finite type morphism over a reduced noetherian scheme. Contrarily to 1), as pointed out by Georges, it can be defined in a much more general setting. Here I can not say a morphism if birational if it is finite type etc. 

Comment: Continued: I think in the book, the word birational is never used out of this situation. For 3), yes I should just restrict to noetherian and not locally noetherian schemes. It is already so hard to desingularize noetherian schemes :). Yes by definition (EGA IV), desingularization morphism are proper, so in particular are of finite type. 

Comment:  Arminius's questions are of course completely legitimate and interesting, but I'd like to emphasize that Qing's book is very well-written and contains an amazing wealth of material. I bought it in 2003 but I am still very far, alas, from having mastered it...

Comment: @Georges: The intention of the second point in my edit above was to make clear that I'm not criticizing Liu Quing, his book, or algebraic geometry in general, and that my questions just emerged from getting confused by some definitions and knowing about experts here who can explain how I have to deal with those. Getting down voted for asking questions about a mathematical textbook (let it be the best written book on earth; I am telling people to take a look at Quing's book instead of Hartshorne's for quite some time now by the way) is something that produces confusion, too.

Comment: @Georges: Moreover, thanks to your link, I think I understand, that my proposal for an alternative definition isn't the right way to do it. Take for example the definition of a smooth morphism in Quing's book: Let $Y$ be locally noetherian and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of finite type. [...]. We say that $f$ is _smooth_ if [...]. Now, I would have changed that to "a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ of schemes is called smooth if it is of finite type, if $Y$ is locally noetherian and if [...]". But due to the more general definition given in the stacks project, this wouldn't be a good

Comment: choice. So the style of definition in Quing's book (which gives the definition in a restricted situation which is probably easier) indeed makes sense as long as one mentions the extra conditions all along.

Comment:  Dear Arminius, it was quite clear to me that you weren't criticizing Qing: I just wanted to state that MY answer wasn't meant as criticism either. I quite agree that it is  unfair to downvote you: I don't advertise my upvotes normally (there are 251), but in this case let me tell you exceptionally that I did upvote you two hours ago.

Comment: Dear Georges, merci pour les compliments ! Dear Arminus, there is no problem critizing my book, and you are wellcome to do it. As I am keep writing an errata, it will help me to improve the book.  

Comment: @Qing: I was pretty sure about that :) I hope you don't take it personal that I keep mixing up your first and last name :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dear Arminius, I'm certainly not going to answer your questions "why doesn't he say...?":
Qing is a frequent and friendly contributor to MO and he will answer  himself if he wants to.

Here is what I think is the consensus about your questions.

1) For a scheme *regular* definitely implies locally noetherian: De Jong 19.8.2

2) Birational necessitates neither  noetherian nor reducedness conditions on schemes nor finite type assumptions on morphisms:  De Jong 20.7.1

3) Qing's definition now makes perfectly good sense in view of 1) and 2). Desingularization is automatically of finite type because a proper morphism is of finite type by definition : De Jong 20.36.1

*Bibliographical note* I didn't want to give a long list of references for the definitions you ask about. I have only quoted  De Jong and collaborators' monumental [Stacks Project](http://math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/) which is the most up-to-date reference and which is incredibly well thought-out. Also De Jong is arguably the mathematician who has made the greatest progress on the resolution of singularities for schemes since Hironaka in 1964 .

Comment: Thank you for the link to Stacks Project! Another 2054 pages to digest (on the plus side: in English; on the minus side: Publ Math IHES are typographically superior). 

Comment: Hurry up, Victor, the number of pages increases almost daily :-)
I completely agree with you that the typography of the Publications de l'IHES is exceptionally beautiful: some modification of Baskerville maybe? [I mean John Baskerville, the type designer, not Conan Doyle's poor Charles, the target of a notorious hound]

Comment: I've been admiring the font of the Publications de l'IHES as well. It is indeed a variation of Baskerville: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16027/font-and-typesetting-of-ega-by-numdam